# WordPress oembed_fetch_url filter not called

Tags: wordpress, oembed

I'm developing WP site. I want the content to display soundcould embedded player within the content.
By default it adds query argument visible-true. What I need is to set this to false. So I'm trying the oembed_fetch_url filter, but It's not event called.
I've searched google all over, there's no information when this filter is even called. I've tried this just to make sure it's working:

```
    function soundcloud_url_change($provider, $url, $args) {
        return "somedummyurl.com";
    }
    add_filter('oembed_fetch_url', 'soundcloud_url_change', 10, 3);
```

The url remained correct. So I have no idea how to manipulate the oembed url.

Comment: Did you solve your problem or did the answer I added help? Curious if you got this working...

Comment: Nope. I know the RyGuy answer should work, but that's an ugly way to do that. It'd be lot easier to work with clean url. The solution provided by RyGuy expects you to extract url from html

Comment: So I'm a little confused now. With the oembed_fetch_url, it seems to me that you're passing arguments to the url on the way out. Wouldn't you want to append the arguments to the url after you've received it from the service? In my case I was only dealing with YouTube so filtering the URL is straight forward. This is interesting though because I didn't have any luck getting arguments to stick when fetching, only on the result.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, your solution would work, but as I said, It's a lot harder to extract url from html. I'm not yet done with this. But I know already that the only way is to change the html

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to hook into the filter:
    oembed_result

I needed to modify the url of a youtube embed and ended up with this block:

```
function mod_oembed_youtube_url($html,$url,$args){
    if(strpos($html, 'youtu.be') !== false || strpos($html, 'youtube.com') !== false){
        $out = preg_replace("@src=(['\"])?([^'\">\s]*)@", "src=$1$2&rel=0", $html);
        return $out;
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('oembed_result','mod_oembed_youtube_url',10,3);
```

This obviously could be more efficient and is only geared for YouTube but hopefully can lead you in the right direction. For reference, the oembed_result is in:

```
/wp-includes/class-oembed.php   Line: 126
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress actually caches the result of the fetch, so if you're running into this, it could be it's [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) before it gets to the filter because it finds the markup in the cache. [Check out this](https://siteorigin.com/clearing-oembed-cache/) for clearing the oembed cache and then see if your filter doesn't run.

That being said, YouTube strips out any query vars you send along, so you'll need to use the other answer listed here for YouTube embeds specifically.